# Custom fonts does not show properly on windows (Chrome)

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, font-size

I have simple static page and I want to import a font. But the font displays very strange on Windows with Google Chrome browser. This font displays properly in other operating systems and browsers.

I imported font by using @font-face like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: NoyhGeometric;
    src: url("../fonts/Typesketchbook - Noyh Geometric Regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("../fonts/Typesketchbook - NoyhGeometric-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

I use Google Chrome browser in both images.

On Ubuntu (displays properly):

[image: a busy cat]

On Windows (displays strange):

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding font smoothing property in you css

```
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Ref: https://davidwalsh.name/font-smoothing

Comment: I tried it, but nothing changed. Font still displays weird on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the browsers support woff/woff2 format for fonts.

Go to [SquirrelFonts](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to convert one  font format with all the others. The website also provides a pre-made CSS for your convenience.

You should add a `.woff` or `woff2` format to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be related to "Clear Type" not be "enabled" and Chrome on Windows apparently needs it to better render fonts. This does not resolve the issue as it cannot be controlled through css and javascript.

Try this page in Chrome on Windows: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Old+Standard+TT
Observer the font not rendering.

Then try going to Start -> Settings -> Type in "Adjust ClearType text" and in the window that opens up check "Turn on Clear Type".

Then restart Chrome, navigate to the same page and observe that the font issue is resolved.